# How to install a (.sty) package on my MiKTeX?

Tags: packages, miktex, installing

I downloaded from "CTAN.org" a package called **arabtex**. I thought it's going to be a file, like `arabtex.sty`. But what happened actually was that it was a folder, and I don't know how to install it on my MiKTeX. BTW, I tried to put it manually by copying and pasting the folder on the following path `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex`. But it didn't work though! 
What should I do?

Comment: Welcome! Please don't shout. It is quite unnecessary as it is always fairly quiet here. Don't download it from CTAN. Instead, use MiKTeX's package manager to install the package. It is included by both MiKTeX and TeX Live so there is no need to install it manually.

Comment: You'll probably have to run `updmap.exe` from the command line, after has been installed, in order to be able to use the fonts.

Comment: I made a **video tutorial** to illustrate the process using the MiKTeX GUI on a Windows 7 system: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OD15rZO_rD8 I am not sure if this qualifies as an answer here. If not I will delete the answer of course.

Comment: @JohnKormylo No the package manager handles *only* packages packaged for miktex. If you manually install a package you must copy the files to the right place and update the FNDB.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer can you explain more, please?

Comment: @user94678: You can find a long explanation in the answer linked by John, but you don't need this currently: arabtex is packaged for miktex and so supported by the package manager.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer | It worked, but the thing is that it doesn't show properly!

Comment: "it doesn't show" is not a sensible problem description.

Comment: If you ever want to download a package that isn't supported by MikTeX, you will still need to use the MikTeX Settings to add the package to the list of sty files. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2063/how-can-i-manually-install-a-package-on-miktex-windows?s=2|0.3394

Comment: You can put .sty file with .tex, when I tried to run own .sty file it run.

Comment: @Giorgi and how to do it?

Comment: when you write "example.tex", put in same directory "mypack.sty", and in tex file write "\usepackage{mypack}" and then it should use the package.